# Package array Error: Illegal pream-token (L): `c' used. \end{tabularx} in KDD template - acmart

Tags: tables, tabularx, document-classes

Here are the package I use and the table. The same runs for other template. Only when I use the KDD template - acmart. I get the above mentioned error.

Here are the packages I use and the table:

```
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}
\usepackage{booktabs,makecell,tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{5pt}
    \small
    \begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{@{}c L S[table-format=7.0]*{2}{S[table-format=2.0]}@{}}
        \toprule
        \thead{ID}  &   \thead{DSA SDADD sdhjk} 
        &   {\thead{ABC \\M}}  
        &   {\thead{ABCD \\ minbucket }} 
        \\
        \midrule
        AB1 & ABCDE abcd                          & 30  & 250     \\
        AB2 & ABCD                                & 40  & 500     \\
        AB3 & ABCD ABCDE ABCDEFG  ABCDEFGH ASDGFF & 2   & 500     \\
        AB4 & ABC ABC 1000                        & 40  & 7       \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \caption{fsdjhkhsdk fhsdjkhdfsjkhkj fsdjhkhsdfk  hjsdfhk}
    \label{table:2}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you have defined a column type `C` and not used it, and used a column type `L` that you have not defined,

Comment: there is no standard L type so if this table runs in another document that document must define L, possibly as you have defined `C` but with `\raggedright` instead of `centering` but that can only be a guess

Comment: using `tabularx` at least one column type had to be based on `X` column type. for example `\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}`. And you use four columns, but have defined five.

Comment: you could simply use tabulary instead of tabularx too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you intended `L` to be defined as below but I would *never* use `tabularx` for such a table, see the version with `tabular`.

`tabularx` is all about adjusting the line breaking within cells to fit a table but you do not want line breaking in such a table and stretching it to full width just makes it hard to read.

[image]

```
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}
\usepackage{booktabs,makecell,tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

%\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{5pt}
    \small
    \begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{@{}c L S[table-format=7.0]*{2}{S[table-format=2.0]}@{}}
        \toprule
        \thead{ID}  &   \thead{DSA SDADD sdhjk} 
        &   {\thead{ABC \\M}}  
        &   {\thead{ABCD \\ minbucket }} 
        \\
        \midrule
        AB1 & ABCDE abcd                          & 30  & 250     \\
        AB2 & ABCD                                & 40  & 500     \\
        AB3 & ABCD ABCDE ABCDEFG  ABCDEFGH ASDGFF & 2   & 500     \\
        AB4 & ABC ABC 1000                        & 40  & 7       \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}

\bigskip

    \begin{tabular}{@{}c l*{2}{S[table-format=2.0]}@{}}
        \toprule
        \thead{ID}  &   \thead{DSA SDADD sdhjk} 
        &   {\thead{ABC \\M}}  
        &   {\thead{ABCD \\ minbucket }} 
        \\
        \midrule
        AB1 & ABCDE abcd                          & 30  & 250     \\
        AB2 & ABCD                                & 40  & 500     \\
        AB3 & ABCD ABCDE ABCDEFG  ABCDEFGH ASDGFF & 2   & 500     \\
        AB4 & ABC ABC 1000                        & 40  & 7       \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}


    \caption{fsdjhkhsdk fhsdjkhdfsjkhkj fsdjhkhsdfk  hjsdfhk}
    \label{table:2}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```